# How can I change the language in Dragon Age:Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'd like to play Dragon Age Inquision in english instead of the language of my operating system, but it seems to default to that and I can't find a way to change it. I already tried setting the Origin client language to english, but that didn't change anything.

Where can I change the language for Dragon Age: Inquisition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking around a bit more I found an additional piece of DLC available for the game, an english voice over pack:

[image]

After slowly downloading the around 2.5 GB I was able to set the text and voice language to english in the audio section of the options menu ingame.

I'm not sure what triggered the availability of the language pack for me, it might simply not have been available when preloading, or it was made available the moment I switched the language of the Origin client to english.

Comment: For me it triggered when I changed ea.com language to English. Still won't let me select English text though, only voice.

Comment: I can't answer because I don't have enough reputation, but it seems like the Voice Over Packs have been pulled from Origin. The only thing that worked for me (german version, wanted english voice over & text) was to set Origin and ea.com to english (latter might be unnecessary) and REINSTALL the game. Origin then downloaded the english language files. You can make a backup of the localized version, start the installation, exit Origin and copy everything except data/win32/loc* to the newly created installation folder. Origin will then only download around 4GB.

Comment: Just an update for my previous comment: The english voice over pack is back in Origin at least in Germany.

Answer (score 5):

I contacted EA support on the matter and found out that the only way to play in English is to get a refund, buy the game in English and then activate it in Origin. You can't buy it from Origin because EA assumes we can't speak other languages than our native.

Answer (score 4):

I am french and I have a similar problem. Yes you have to download the langage pack. And you also have to go here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Dragon Age Inquisition\Data\Win32`

1. In the folder `loctext` leave only the files `en.sb` and `en.toc` present, put the others in a folder named temp
2. In the folder `locfacefx` make a copy of `en.sb_DiP_STAGED` and `en.toc_DiP_STAGED`, rename them to `en.sb` and `en.toc`. place the other language files into a temp folder

When I started the game the language was changed also into the interface. Take notes on what you have done and keep the original files in case something doesn't work, but for the moment that seem to work.

Also there is a way to change the text language if your copy is region blocked like mine, which only has russian text available no matter how many other lang files are in the folder. It won't let you pick another, and if you leave only the en file it says there are no supported languages available. So what you need to do is rename both en files to `ru` (I'll give the example for my own language, others work similar). But that isn't all, you need to edit them for the game to work.
I used Notepad++ for this. You open them and replace `/en/` by `/ru/` in both files. After that you just save them and run the game, enjoying the english text.

Comment: If you don't have `en.sb_DiP_STAGED` and `en.toc_DiP_STAGED`, acquire them via any available legal means, and replace them as required.