# Changing the game's text language to English

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

In the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192063/how-can-i-change-the-language-in-dragon-ageinquisition/192139#192139), I was advised:

> Yes you have to download the language pack. And you also have to go here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Dragon Age Inquisition\Data\Win32`
>
> In the folder `loctext` leave only the files `en.sb` and `en.toc` present, put the others in a folder named `temp`.
>   In the folder locfacefx make a copy of `en.sb_DiP_STAGED` and `en.toc_DiP_STAGED`, rename them to `en.sb` and `en.toc`. place the other language files into a temp folder
>   When I started the game the language was changed also into the interface. Take notes on what you have done and keep the original files in case something doesn't work, but for the moment that seem to work."

I have no `en.sb_DiP_STAGED` and `en.toc_DiP_STAGED` files in my Origin version of the game.

Comment: Did you do the required download for your language pack?

Answer (score 4):

Also there is a way to change the text language if your copy is regionblocked like mine, which only has russian text available no matter how many other lang files are in the folder. It won't let you pick another, and if you leave only the en file it says there are no supported languages available. So what you need to do is rename both en files to ru(i'll give the example for my own language, others work similar). But that isn't all, you need to edit them for the game to work. I used Notepad++ for this. You open them, and replace, without quotes, "/en/" with "/ru/" in both files. After that you just save them and run the game, enjoying the english text.

Comment: Sir, I love you so much!  You just made my day (and next week or two). This is community wiki material (unless it is in some way illegal). Could you please make another question and answer it yourself, so it does not get lost?

Comment: @letitbee Actually, we don't allow duplicate questions that ask the same thing.  We tend to frown on such activities, in fact, so please don't recommend answerers do so.

Comment: This is clearly not about the same thing. Question is about some european versions with non-english VO that are not region locked, and this answer is about region-locked russian version, where you get russian text and english VO and if you try to add english text files you get an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can confirm that a similar procedure (with ru replaced with pl) works for Polish version as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to search for an additional download in Origin.

Search for "Dragon Age Inquisition dubbed in English" or something similar in the store.
You have to fake a purchase of this dlc (it's free) and to download 2,61 GB of additional data.