# Why i can't put DA:I In English?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

In trial the game was in ENGLISH but by some reason after i have purchased, the game comes "language locked". Why they do this? I've played RPG's in English since my childhood, work with native speakers, played DA:O in English and ... Can`t play the game in English? Why the trial is in English and there are no information about "language lock" on store?

I`ve tried 5 different tutorials to put the game in English, even change the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\BioWare\Dragon Age Inquisition

Locale to en_EN and GDFBinary to GDFBinary_en_EN.dll and nothing works. The translation s***s. The abilities description makes no sense and the use of therms that nobody uses in my home country such as "melindroso" is ridiculous. Looks like a google translation translation of a google translation translation. I wanna play in ENGLISH. I've tried to get a refund since the game is unplayable with this piece of **** translation but the refund """failed""". Thanks for punishing someone who purchased a original copy while people who don't follow the rules and prejudices the game industry can play in any language that they want.

Note that : 
1 - The trial was in English
2 - According to ORIGIN store of my region ENGLISH IS A SUPPORTED LANGUAGE

[image: ENGLISH IS SHOWED AS A AVAILABLE LANGUAGE]

3 - I did not see any advised about language lock
4 - I have tried to enter in contact with origin support. According to the site the waiting time is 5 minutes but in reality... 30 minutes and nobody appears.

**EDIT >** Is different(not duplicate) because the other questions works for the 2014 game. After the recent updates, the solution isn't working. So i need a solution to 2017 version of the game.

---

**EDIT 2** HOW I managed to put DA:I to English

Since the other solutions works only with older versions, i decided to download old version files then use the another method. Finally works. The unique small problem is that i will be forced to play the tutorial again because

[image: Saves are incompatible]

Comment: ...You do know that we're not Origin or EA support, right?

Comment: Someone can come with a real solution to put the game in English. Right?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no solution in related topics. In some cases they say to edit to /en/ but no mention about what file i need edit https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192147/changing-the-games-text-language-to-english?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Okay, so have you followed the steps from the other question?  You haven't told us what you've tried, just sorta ranted about Origin and said you tried some things without giving us details.

Comment: Yep. You are right. Using the hints from other topics, i've found only messages about error in licence, "not found language" and etc. Since the posts are old, EA probably have patched and i don't know how to play in English...

Answer (score 1):

Downloading and installing the free English Voice Over Pack should allow you to play the game in its original English audio version.

[image: Dragon Age: Inquisition Voice Over Pack]

To get this pack, open Origin to your Game library, open the Extra Content tab, and scroll down to the bottom of the add-ons until you reach it. It should be somewhere near the bottom.

[image: Origin tab for DA:I] -> [image: DAI English Voice Over Pack listing]

---

Since the game is region-locked for the text language, you can't change that as easily as the audio portion. You can find English text files and replace your text files with them while making sure to change all \en\ in them to whatever language code you had. The text files are located in Origin Games\Dragon Age Inquisition\Data\Win32\loctext. [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/3o46vb/no_spoilers_english_subtitles_in_nonenglish/) should have a link to English text packs for patch 11 of the game.

Comment: This only change the **AUDIO** language. I need put **TEXT IN ENGLISH** to be able to play the game.

Comment: @Victor Edited. Also I realize you're angry, but we're just regular gamers trying to help here, so maybe should tone it down a smidge.

Comment: Sorry, i should be angry with EA, not with regular games that wanna help me. This solution only works with old version. Thanks a lot for trying help. I managed to download old files and after used your method, the game is now in English. Thanks a lot.